# Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance, hasMany

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

```
$users = User::all();
//dd($users);
return view('welcome')->with('users',$users);
```

I pass the `$users` to view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)

    <li>{{$user->contact->name}}</li>

    @endforeach
```

I want to use name properties from contact.  When I use `{{$user->contact}}` I have output:

```
[{"id":6,"user_id":1,"name":"Maximillian O'Kon III","created_at":"2018-04-02 16:27:05","updated_at":"2018-04-02 16:27:05"},{"id":9,"user_id":1,"name":"Prof. Raul Runolfsdottir","created_at":"2018-04-02 16:27:05","updated_at":"2018-04-02 16:27:05"},{"id":12,"user_id":1,"name":"Marcos Marquardt","created_at":"2018-04-02 17:48:23","updated_at":"2018-04-02 17:48:23"},{"id":17,"user_id":1,"name":"Malinda Windler","created_at":"2018-04-02 17:48:23","updated_at":"2018-04-02 17:48:23"},{"id":18,"user_id":1,"name":"Gabe Bogisich","created_at":"2018-04-02 17:48:23","updated_at":"2018-04-02 17:48:23"}]..**and so on there are some empty collection** []
```

This is the user class:

```
 public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
    }
```

Comment: `$user->contact` is a `Collection`, not a single instance of `Contact`; you need to loop it or use `$user->contact->first()->name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using one-to-many [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), it is better to use plural form  so you do not get confused, and you know it is [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections), instead of single instance.

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
}
```

To access the contact name:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @foreach ($user->contacts as $contact)
        <li>{{$contact->name}}</li>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```